# Google Play Console: Advertising ID error while uploading the app

Tags: expo, google-play, android-13

I have the same message in the Google Play Console as described here: You must complete the advertising ID declaration before releasing an app that targets Android 13 5 and I guess it’s because I use Expo-notifications Which seems to use Firebase ,but I couldn’t find any confirmation of that guess. I don’t use advertising ID otherwise.
Can someone confirm that Expo-notifications does use this ID and if I should answer yes to this question. Or do you know a tool to scan my app so I can see if some of my packages require advertising ID permission ?
Thanks in advance